# Replicate Stata 'variance' and 'robust' in R for mixed effects methods

Tags: regression, mixed-model, stata, sas, clustered-standard-errors

I am working with a small dataset of clustered data. The experiment is on mice, testing the efficacy of a substance for neurons cells within mice, and delivery of a fatty acid substance between mice. This results in interesting within and between effects.

The authors have published their results ([article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146721), [github](https://github.com/elmoen/clustered_data_code))

However, their results were from the outputs provided in Stata. When reproducing in R (or SAS), I am getting very different results for the standard errors.

Using lme in R, is there a clearer way of reproducing the robust standard errors and variance options provided by in Stata?

Answer (score 1):

There are various versions of robust standard errors, e.g., using the sandwich estimator, (grouped) jackknife, the Bootstrap method. It is not clear which one you are looking for.

The [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package implements the sandwich estimator for mixed models; for more info check [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#detailed-output-confidence-intervals-covariance-matrix-of-the-mles-and-robust-standard-errors).